# Ghostscript wrapper that works with byte arrays rather than file directories

Tags: c#, ghostscript

I'm using a [generic C# wrapper](http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/06/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ghostscript/) to render images from PDFs after a user uploads a file and I'm wondering whether its possible to configure the wrapper to work with byte arrays rather than actual files on disk as this will save me an extra trip and increase my application's performance. Ideally I want to pass a byte array of the PDF and have it return a byte array. I had look at the wrapper code and I can't figure out how exactly (if even possible) I would do this. So is it possible? If so any guidance as to where I should start?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't feed a sequence of bytes to the Ghostscript PDF interpreter, nor read back a PDF file as a sequence of bytes produced by the pdfwrite device.

The reason is simply that the PDF interpreter, and the PDF writer, both need random access to the file in order to interpret/create the file. If the whole file were held in memory then it would be possible to do so, but that would be a severe limitation on the size of files.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper you are using is pure wrapper does not provide you what you need. Take a look at [**Ghostscript.NET**](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/) managed Ghostscript wrapper (full implementation) which allows you to run interpret prolog / postscript and multiple instances of Ghostscript library at a same time if you have a need to process multiple pdf's at a same time. There is a class [GhostscriptViewerPdfFileHandler](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Ghostscript.NET/Ghostscript.NET/Viewer/FileHandlers/GhostscriptViewerPdfFileHandler.cs) which demonstrates you how to manipulate pdf through the interpreter. Everything you need can be done.

Comment: Does Ghostscript.NET allow for parllel programming?

Comment: From what i know Ghostscript library is not thread safe that is why only once instance per process can be created. Ghostscript.NET allows you to load Ghostscript library from the memory which allows you to run multiple instances of the Ghostscript library each one in it's own memory space. I tested Ghostscript.NET as much as i could and it shows that for now there is no problem running each Ghostscript instance in it's own thread in a single process.

Comment: About the parallel programming: Ghostscript library has a switch (-dNumRenderingThreads) which allows you to take advantage of more than one CPU. Ghostscript memory usage can be also increased by using (-c) switch. (sample: -c "30000000 setvmthreshold" should increase maximum Ghostscript memory usage up to 30 MB.